# How to route directory calls correctly in app.yaml?

Tags: .htaccess, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, php-5.5

I want to mimic this **.htaccess** rewrite, in Google App Engine **app.yaml** using PHP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ query.php?q=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've done this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
  # mod_rewrite by forwarding the requests to query.php?q=...
  - url: /services/(.+)
    script: services/query.php?q=\1

  # Serve images as static resources.
  - url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|svg))$
    static_files: \1
    upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|svg)$
    application_readable: true

  - url: /(.+\.(html))$
    static_files: \1
    upload: .+\.(html)$
    application_readable: true

  # Serve php scripts.
  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    script: \1

  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
    application_readable: true
```

But the result is always not found error:

> "POST /services/login HTTP/1.1" 404

I think the handlers not catching it. Any clue to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that - the `script:` statement is not for specifying a full URL (with its query string), it's just for specifying the path to the script. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element):

> **script**
>
> Optional. Specifies the path to the script from the application root
>   directory:
>
> ```
> ...
> handlers:
> - url: /profile/(.*)/(.*)
>   script: /employee/\2/\1.php  # specify a script
> ```

You can easily confirm that by replacing `script: services/query.php?q=\1` with `script: services/query.php` in your first handler. If the `services/query.php` script starts getting invoked it means the pattern matching worked fine and the problem was the script specification - `services/query.php?q=\1` is not a valid script file path.